# ReactJS show modal popup form on specified keystroke

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, reactjs, keyevent

I am new to ReactJS. I am writing the frontend to a web application. My application needs to display several modal dialogues - each one displayed for a given key combination. I intend to use JQuery-UI for the modal dialogbox.

The table below gives a rough idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
Dialog Name     |     Key combination (required to popup/display modal dialog)
==============================================================================
ModalDialog1    |     Ctrl-X
ModalDialog2    |     Shift + K
ModalDialog2    |     Alt + Shift + M

etc ....
```

I am "hiding" the modal forms in the header of the page (using css to set display to none) - is this best practise?

This is what my home page looks like:

//index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is what my App.js and other React components looks like:

```
var React = require('react');
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var PageHeader = require('./PageHeader');
var TopPanelLeftWindow = require('./TopPanelLeftWindow');
var TopPanelRightWindow = require('./TopPanelRightWindow');
var BottomPanel = require('./BottomPanel');


var App = React.createClass({

    render(){

        return (

            <div>
                <div id="header">
                    <PageHeader />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div><TopPanelLeftWindow/ ></div>
                        <div><TopPanelRightWindow/ ></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div><BottomPanel/ ></div>              
                </div>

            </div>

        );
    }

});

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, window.document.getElementById("main"));
```

//PageHeader.js

```
var React = require('react');

var ModalDialogue1 = require('./ModalDialogue1');
var ModalDialogue2 = require('./ModalDialogue2');


var PageHeader = React.createClass({

    render(){

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="hiddenModalDialogs">
                    <div className="invisible"><ModalDialogue1 /></div>
                    <div className="invisible"><ModalDialogue2 /></div>
                    <!-- etc .. ->
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

});

module.exports = PageHeader;
```

I have two questions:

1. Is the way I'm "hiding" the modal dialogues best practise for ReactJs webapps?
2. How do I bind the keystrokes to the modal dialogboxes so that they are displayed when the keystroke combination is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different approach to hide an element in a React.js app. I think that React's state is the way to go here. In the `App` component I would add state attributes to decide whether a modal should be shown or not. Then I would send that attributes as props to the `PageHeader` Component. Finally, you could implement a prop in the Modal itself to decide whether it should be shown or not (maybe changing a css className) and send it the value you got from the state of the `App` component.

I made a snippet showing an example without a modal where I just hide or show an element by returning or not returning it from the parent.

```js
class Header extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    render() {
        let modal1;
        if(this.props.showHeaderModal1){
          modal1=<h1>THIS SHOULD BE A MODAL</h1>;
          }
        return (
          <div>
          {modal1}
          </div>
               );
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          showHeaderModal1: false,
        };
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    }

    toggle() {
        this.setState({
           showHeaderModal1: !this.state.showHeaderModal1,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
        <div>
          <Header showHeaderModal1={this.state.showHeaderModal1} />
          <button onClick={this.toggle}>TOGGLE</button>
        </div>
        
        ); <div>{view}</div>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Finally, I found [this package](https://github.com/glortho/react-keydown) to detect the ketstrokes. I haven't tried it but I guess that you would basically have to use it instead of the button in the App component.